# only allow CSS hover event after timeout using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I want to only allow a hover event when an element has been un-hovered for a timeout period, if the mouse re-enters the hovered element I want it to act as if the mouse never left.

**ex:** a navigation has a dropdown on CSS :hover, if the users mouse goes outside the hovered element by mistake the dropdown instantly dissapears, instead I would like to set a timer to check if the mouse has been unhovered for more than 500ms, if so close the dropdown; if the mouse has re-entered in that time period stop the closing event and leave menu open.

**HTML::**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>ghetto nav item 1
      <ul>
        <li>awful Dropdown item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>ghetto nav item 2</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS::**

```
nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    display: none;
}
nav > ul > li:hover + ul > li {
    display: block;
}
```

**JS::**
??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using CSS3.  Apply `transition-delay` with the `height` of the element, instead of toggling `display`:

```css
nav > ul > li > ul > li {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
  transition-delay: 0s;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>ghetto nav item 1
      <ul>
        <li>awful Dropdown item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>ghetto nav item 2</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: giggidy thats just clean and glorious. Ive been going to hard on the JS lately. thanks! I didn't know about transition delay